# How to configure masters/slaves machines for hadoop 1.2.1 cluster

Tags: hadoop

In my conf/masters I have current pc name: pc01

In my conf/slaves I have other pc name: pc02

When i start hadoop, (all starts ok), but when I go to the Browser, to check status, shows Live Nodes:0.

When I try on local, without using masters and slaves, browser shows Live Nodes: 1

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Is ssh between master and slaves set up correctly? If yes, are your DNS records ok so that Hadoop can perform (reverse) DNS lookups?

[This might help to answer the above question: [https://github.com/sujee/hadoop-dns-checker]](https://github.com/sujee/hadoop-dns-checker)